# Can the Case and CiviCase tags be synonymized?

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

If that's even a real word. I don't have enough points to suggest this directly on the synonyms page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure thing. Done! Also, I apparently need at least 30 characters to tell you that it's done.

Comment: Thanks!........